# butterknife Required view 'hello' with ID 2131427413 for field 'hello' was not found

Tags: android, butterknife

`Butterknife` I use `@bindView` to annotate Button.
But it was happened a error.
`Required view 'hello' with ID 2131427413 for field 'hello' was not found.`

```
@BindView(R.id.hello)
Button hello;
@Inject
GitHubApiService gitHubApiService;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    hello.setText("hello");
}
```

butterknife's dependencies

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'//这个是自定义注解用的编译插件

buildscript {

    repositories {

        jcenter()

    }

    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.4.0'

    }

}
```

Comment: You didn't `setContentView` of the Activity

Comment: You can try to clean Project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set the content view before calling `ButterKnife.bind(this)` like below:

```
 setContentView(R.layout.your_view);
 ButterKnife.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!I found reason myself.

Before I add the following  in `build.gradle of app module`.
But the following should be add to `build.gradle of project`

```
    >classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    >classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.4.0'

    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.4.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also check that in `setContentView(R.layout.your_view);` you are passing the right layout